# get data-attributes passed to an element after the page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am relatively new in javascript and jquery. 
I am trying to create and customize a `<input type="file">`. So I hide it from the view and trigger when customer click in another `a` element.

So basically my input looks like this

```
<input type="file" style="display:none;" id="myFile">
```

And my a element like this

```
<a href="#" class="add_image" data-index="0" data-conind="1"><i class="fa fa-picture-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i> Choose Image</a>
```

So to achieve this and pass the data-attributtes to the input I did:

```
//open select of image
    $(document).on('click','.add_image',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var att = $(this).data();
        $.each(att,function(index,val) {
           $('#myFile').attr(index,val); 
        });
        $('#myFile').trigger('click');
    });
```

The idea is after the customer choose the image fire an onChange event to upload the image. But I need the data attributes.

```
$(document).on('change','#myFile',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
console.log($(this).data());
});
```

In this case I got the attributes as null or undefined

Comment: Are you trying to add attribute to `$('#myFile')` before triggering it?

Comment: yes! I want to pass the attirbutes to #myFile, then trigger and get the attributes again

Comment: Try using `element.setAttribute(attributename, attributevalue)`

Comment: but the attributes are passed properly.. the problem is that I can not retrieve them when I trigger the onChange event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set data attributes using [`.data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) and not `.attr`

```js
$(document).on('click', '.add_image', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var att = $(this).data();
  $.each(att, function(index, val) {
    $('#myFile').data(index, val);
  });
  $('#myFile').trigger('click');
});

$(document).on('change', '#myFile', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).data());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" style="display:none;" id="myFile">

<a href="#" class="add_image" data-index="0" data-conind="1"><i class="fa fa-picture-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i> Choose Image</a>
```

You may need to choose a file in the file popup to see the console.log (as it only logs on change)